# windres: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#, mingw, windres

I'm using windows 10.

I'm trying to compile a c++ file within c# using MinGW(the MinGW folder is in the projects directory), but it won't compile a resource script (using windres).

Whenever I use windres in cmd it says: "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/my.rc:1: unrecognized escape sequence".
but still works.
But when I run the exact same command through c# (by creating a process) it doesn't work at all and says: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.".

My code:

```
String tempDir = Path.GetTempPath();
String file = tempDir + "my.rc";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.ASCII))
{
     if (!textIcon.Text.Equals(""))
         await writer.WriteLineAsync("25 ICON \"" + textIcon.Text + "\"");
     if (checkAdmin.Checked)
     {
         String manifest = tempDir + @"\manifest.xml";
         createManifest(manifest);
         await writer.WriteLineAsync("55 24 \"" + manifest + "\"");
     }
}

String args2 = "/c \"" + Path.Combine(gccLocation, "windres.exe") + "\" -o \"" + Path.Combine(tempDir, "my.o").Replace("\\", "/") + "\" \"" + file.Replace("\\", "/") + "\"";

//Debug
//args2 = "/k echo " + args2;

ProcessStartInfo psi2 = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi2.FileName = "CMD.exe";
psi2.Arguments = args2;
psi2.UseShellExecute = false;
psi2.CreateNoWindow = true;

//Debug
//psi2.CreateNoWindow = false;

Process windres = Process.Start(psi2);
windres.WaitForExit();

if(windres.ExitCode != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not create resource file (" + windres.ExitCode + ")");
}
```

Comment: The arguments it passes to cmd are:
/c "MinGW\bin\windres.exe" -o "C:/Users/easyc/AppData/Local/Temp/my.o" "C:/Users/easyc/AppData/Local/Temp/my.rc"

Comment: That can only work consistently when you set ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory so it can reliably find the MinGW subdirectory.  Always favor full path names, c:\foo\bar\baz.ext

Comment: I added in this bit of code:

if (!File.Exists(gccLocation + @"windres.exe"))
                        MessageBox.Show("windres doesn't exist");
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("windres exists.");

and the messagebox says "windres exists".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a batch file to run the command.

```
                String args2 = "windres.exe -i \"" + Path.GetFullPath(file) + "\" -o \"" + Path.Combine(tempDir, "my.o") + "\"" ;

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempDir + @"\my.bat", false, Encoding.ASCII))
                {
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync("@echo off");
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync("cd " + Path.GetFullPath(gccLocation));
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(args2);
                }

                //Debug
                //args2 = "/k echo " + args2;

                ProcessStartInfo psi2 = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi2.FileName = tempDir + @"\my.bat";
                psi2.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi2.CreateNoWindow = true;

                //Debug
                //psi2.CreateNoWindow = false;

                Process windres = Process.Start(psi2);
                windres.WaitForExit();
```